# Change a specific status after a few days from a date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where our agents updated about the emails being sent and the responses received. If they send an email out, they will update the status as "Sent". If they get a response for the email sent, they will change the status to "Client not interested" or "send more details" or some other statuses based on the reply received from the drop-down.

We enter the date in a column by when we sent the email. From that day we wait for three days to get a reply and if it was not received, then the "sent" status should disappear from cell wherever it appears in the status column.

Basically if we did not receive any reply after 3 days from the date of sending the email, the status set as "Sent", should disappear which we understand as "no reply received" for the email sent.

I am not skilled with scripts. I need your help to add a script for this as we will be sending many emails everyday and automating this particular thing will help us a lot. Thanks in advance.

Best
Joe

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you will want to utilize an onEdit trigger.  [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

And you will have to set up data validation for The Status Column and that can be accomplished through the Data Menu.

Most well writtten onEdit functions are similar to this:

```
function onEdit(e) {//e is population by the triggers event object
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if( sh.getName() == "your sheet name" && e.columnStart == "column number of status column" && e.range.rowStart > "header row"  ) {
    //enter the rest of your code in here and all other edits on this and other pages will not enter this code and be returned as quickly as possible
  }
}
```

After you've learned a little more about how the onEdit work you may wish to reconsidered how you would like things to work because a good design is typically a compromise between the user interface and the complexity of the software.

Comment: Thanks Cooper. I will check how it works. However, the "sent" status will not change on edit. It will change to a blank cell if we did not receive a reply from the recipient after 3 days from the date of sending the email. App script must look for the date and the status column. if it is more than 3 days and status remain "sent", this status should be deleted (set that cell to blank again) for that particular row / recipient.